# grunt watch using lots of cpu on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs, towerjs

I'm using grunt to watch my coffeescript files in a towerjs project and recompile them as they change. The configuration for this is generated by towerjs and seems fairly sane. The problem is, that once I start this process I will see it pegging a cpu core (actually, just one hyperthread). If I remove a lot of the paths from being watched I can get it down to around 25% of a CPU, but that is still pretty terrible.

I've found a few references to some known issues and cross-platform inconsistence with the Node's fs API and even the fs.watch [in particular](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor/issues/71). Tried [grunt-simple-watch](https://github.com/unbalanced/grunt-simple-watch) but it did not do any better.

I could setup Guard but it may be fiddlesome to get it working just right and functionally grunt seems to be just fine - I am curious though if anyone else has any other suggestions.

Comment: Give the new watch task a try: `npm install grunt-contrib-watch` and add `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');` to your gruntfile. The Grunt v0.3 watch task traverses & stats files which with a large number of files can get slow but was necessary for system compatibility. The new one will only use inotify if working properly within node.

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung that worked, thanks! submit as answer?

Comment: Ha sure. If you run into any issues with it feel free to submit an issue on github. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the new watch task a try: `npm install grunt-contrib-watch` and add `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');` to your gruntfile. The Grunt v0.3 watch task traverses & stats files which with a large number of files can get slow but was necessary for system compatibility. The new one will only use inotify if working properly within node.

Comment: got the same cpu issue on windows 8. I'm using `grunt-contrib-watch`

Comment: Make sure your patterns are not running off matching 1000s of files. Number 1 reason for high cpu usage.